# Descending Mergesort

Tags: c++

I wrote some code to perform descending Merge Sort.

```
void Merge(int a[], int low, int high, int mid)
{

int i=low,j=mid+1,k=0;
int temp[high-low+1];

while(i<=mid && j<= high)
{
    if(a[i]>a[j])               //comparison step
        temp[k++]=a[i++];

    else
        temp[k++]=a[j++];

}

while(i<=mid)
    {
        temp[k++]=a[i++];
    }

while(j<=high)
    {
        temp[k++]=a[j++];
    }

for(i=low;i<=high;i++)
{

    a[i]=temp[i-low];

}


return;
}


void MergeSort(int a[],int low, int high)
 {
int mid;

if(low<high)
{
    mid=(low+high)/2;

    MergeSort(a,low,mid);
    MergeSort(a,mid+1,high);

    Merge(a,low,high,mid);
}

return;
}


void output(int *a,int n)
{
 for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     cout<<a[i]<<"\t";
 }
}

int main()
{
 int n=12;
 int a[n]={23,45,1,2,8,0,9,56,73,5070,20,16};
 MergeSort(a,0,n);
 output(a,n);

}
```

This code works perfectly when the order is ascending, ie. comparsion is a[i] < a[j]

However by using a[j] > a[i] MergeSort beings sorting in descending order, but it will include some random large number right at the beginning of the array. I really can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: Instead of the code that (allegedly) works, show the code that doesn't work. Make that a complete example that readers can just copy and paste and compile to try out.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Okay

Comment: Also please format properly. No one wants to read poorly formatted code without getting paid. *(Or even if they get paid...)*

Comment: I think you are going out of bounds on your array. In your `Merge` function you are allowing `j<=high`, but you pass the length of the array as `high` to `MergeSort`. Looks like you have an off by 1 error. You might want to think about passing `n-1` to `Mergesort` and then re-tracing your code.

Comment: @MFisherKDX I don't think thats the problem because the code doesn't go out of bounds when MergeSort is ascending

Comment: Try debugging it with a smaller array -- 3 elements. Watch what happens to your indices.

Comment: Note that variable size arrays (i.e., `int temp[high - low + 1];`) are **not** part of standard C++ (they are an extension of some compilers like `g++`, though). Using stack-based temporary memory is also problematic when trying to deal with larger inputs as you'll get a stack overflow: the stack is relatively small. Use `std::vector<int> temp(high - low + 1);` instead.

Comment: @user3397: actually @MFisherKDX is correct: your loop access an out of bound value as your `MergeSort()` treats the range `[low, high]` as inclusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C++ are zero based. However, your code happily access `a[high]` which gets passed the value `12`. Thus, you got an out of bounds access. The same error happens if you sort your array ascending but since you don't print `a[12]` (you `output()` function uses a range exclusive of `n`) you don't see it.

I *strongly* recommend to adopt a programming style where ranges are *inclusive* of the start value and *exclusive* of the end value. Of course, I'd also recommend using iterators for ranges rather than indices anyway. For these the convention is more obvious.

The quick fix (which doesn't change how your `MergeSort()` to be exclusive of the last element) is to apply two changes:

1. Change the termination check in `MergeSort()` to become

   ```
   if (1 < high - low)
   ```
2. Call `MergeSort()` with the last element of the array

   ```
   MergeSort(a, 0, n - 1);
   ```

Note that variable sized built-in arrays like `int temp[high - low + 1]` are *not* part of standard C++ even though they are supported by some compilers as an extension (e.g., `g++`). For bigger arrays they also cause problems as they are bound to overflow the stack. You are much better off using `std::vector<int>`:

```
std::vector<int> temp(high - low + 1);
```

For the test array you can use a static sized array for which the compiler determines the size and have the compiler also figure out the array:

```
 int a[]={23,45,1,2,8,0,9,56,73,5070,20,16};
 int n = std::end(a) - std::begin(a); // need <iterator> to be included
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot of what you said makes sense, I'll try to follow the convention of keeping end values to be exclusive. But could be explain what you meant by using iterators instead of indices ?

Comment: Like @MFisherKDX said, it works when I pass n-1  as the end value in MergeSort. Why is change no. 1 necessary as well?

Comment: @user3397 Check 1 is not necessary. Because if you have an array of 2 elements the inclusive range would be [low=0, high=1]. And then `1 < high - low` is false and the array would not be sorted.